# PHP5-CGI taking up too much load, second is MYSQL, third is APACHE

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I recently moved to a new server and I am experiencing very high PHP5-CPI. I am running a forum that holds up to 450 people every 20 minutes. My forum ran very well a month a go for the longest time (almost 7 months, no complaints). I am trying to figure out what is causing this, because I already hired a person to check if there are any memory leaks anywhere in the code (it is SMF), and he did an excellent job decreasing the queries. Is this an APACHE problem? Could this be caused by an APACHE misconfiguration? The high memory is causing my session tables and log tables to break, leading to even more high memory usage. Let me know if you can help :(